# accelerometer - Movement pattern recognition (iphone)

Tags: iphone, accelerometer, pattern-recognition

I have to find the best approach for tackling a problem for trying to recognize physical movements - with an iPhone in a pocket - like waling, stopping, turning left/right, sitting.

I was thinking on just heuristically find the data corresponding to each action, then to check the incoming values against this data (with a threshold) and see what's happening. 
That's a very rough approach, of course, so maybe using something like the [Support Vector Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) 
methods, but this seems too complicated for the amount of time I have to develop this.

Which approach would you suggest here?

Answer (score 6):

**Walking**: Do an fft on the gravity direction signal. Measure its frequency response for walking at different speeds and then set a simple threshold.

**Stopping**: if the average power i.e. total energy in the signal over the last few seconds drops below a certain threshold then you can say the user has stopped.

**Turning left,right**: Use the gravity vector and the gyroscopes rotation speed vector to determine whether the user is rotating clockwise or counterclockwise

**Sitting**: This will be very hard to determine but if youre lucky the SVM will find the right pattern.

Each of the above can be given a weighting and then you will have to find a good way to obtain training data to train your SVM. Maybe stream the signals from the phone to a webserver and simultaneously record the users motions by hand.

Your best starting point is Apples Sample code: CoreMotionTeapot

Alternatively you could analyze the GPS signal. This will give you a very good way to determine the users larger scale motion like walking/moving or changing heading etc.

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions, I'll try some of them. Unfortunately I've never used a SVM, so I think 5 days won't be enough for setting a working SVM pattern recognition. So I'll have to figure out the sitting and turning parts with a rougher and more direct approach. Anyway I have to specifically use only the accelerometer, so no gyro nor gps signal.

Comment: Yep, 5 days wont be enough to learn about SVMs. You also wont be able to determine turning with the just accelerometer. If you can use the onboard compass youll easily be able to do turning.

Comment: when turning very quickly the x-axis changes slightly, but it doesn't seem reliable. So is safe that I just conclude that recognizing left/right turns when walking isn't feasible with the accelerometer? Why would be the reason for that? also no compass.

Comment: accelerometers detect translational motion, gyroscopes detect rotational motion. if you have an iphone 3g and up then you have a gps. 3gs and up have compass. iphone 4 has a gyro.

Comment: do you have any idea on how to tackle the sitting recognition? I was thinking about collecting data when sitting down from stading up and viceversa, and just see which and how the axes change values, but the situation is more complex since the iphone's initial position is an unknown.

Comment: also: do you think it's possible to recognize when climbing stairs?